# Video unavailable. Watch on Youtube problem

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a problem about Youtube iOS SDK (youtube-ios-player-helper). I am able to use it in my iOS native code now and it's working fine.

The problem is there are some videos which unable to watch on the application. The video iframe shows this:

[Youtube video problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66vI2.jpg)

Can anyone find any ways to pass through it? Or maybe is there any parameters for the search API which filter those kinds of video out of my results?

My search API is [https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=Mật](https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=M%E1%BA%ADt) vụ bóng đêm&maxResults=50&type=video with region VN.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I guess you are talking about this video [SZY4qcEGJto](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SZY4qcEGJto). If you could share us a network dump of the device while this error is loaded, like in [pcap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap) format, or more precisely the HTTP request returning the error. Likewise we will be able to modify this HTTP request to know for any video whether or not it is available in this context.